# How to get parameters of a async function corresponding to a callback after return in Node?

Tags: node.js

I have a `nodejs` function as shown below

```
function sample(a, b) {

    var params = {
        a: a,
        b: b
    };

    myService.doMyJob(params, function(err, response) {
        if (err) 
            //do something

        //access params.a and params.b

    });
}
```

This function gets called multiple times with different values of `a` and `b`. Is there a way to get the values of `a` and `b` corresponding to the callback returned?

NOTE : Logically, I cannot return the values of `a` and `b` from the service along with the success callback result.

Answer (score 0):

your code should work as it is. the callback function will have closure around the `params` object, allowing it to access the values you want.

for example:

```
var myService = {
  doMyJob: function(params, cb){
    return cb();
  }
};

function sample(a, b) {

    var params = {
        a: a,
        b: b
    };

    myService.doMyJob(params, function(err, response) {
        if (err)  { throw err; }

        //access params.a and params.b
        console.log(params.a);
        console.log(params.b);

    });
}

sample("a", "b");
```

this will console.log:

> a
>
> b

**update from comments below**

here is a version that uses a loop, and makes it async using setTimeout.

```
var myService = {
  doMyJob: function(params, cb){
    setTimeout(function(){
      return cb();
    }, 50);
  }
};

function sample(a, b) {

    var params = {
        a: a,
        b: b
    };

    myService.doMyJob(params, function(err, response) {
        if (err)  { throw err; }

        //access params.a and params.b
        console.log(params.a, params.b);
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
  sample("a" + i, "b" + i);
}
```

i'm not sure how you're ending up with the wrong values of `params`. is there anything else in your code that is not represented in this sample code?

can you provide sample code that replicates the problem, accurately?

Comment: In the first iteration, assume, params.a =1 and params.b=2. In the second iteration, assume, params.a=3 and params.b=4. The sample(a,b) is invoked within a for loop. The call to myService.doMyJob gets collected and is returned when the for loop ends. So at this point of time, params.a and params.b have the latest values. How do i solve this? I would want the corresponding values of params.a and params.b of the function call inside the callback.

Comment: i'm not sure how that's happening... i've updated my code sample to use a loop and be async. can you provide a complete working example that reproduces the problem?